# Today extension is not working in iOS 14 beta

Tags: ios, android-appwidget, today-extension, ios14

I tried running my app on iOS 14 beta which is just released. And surprisingly I don't see today extension in the phone anymore which was working all good till iOS 13+. Will today extensions not work anymore on iOS 14 since App Widgets are introduced..?

Comment: I'm developing a ios widget So if I need to develop a new widget for ios, don't I need to build both Widget Extension and Today Extension version?

Comment: It should not be necessary for iOS 14.. Not sure about the backward compatibility though.

Comment: For ios 14 and later, we use widget extension and we decide to abandon ios 13.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 14 beta appears to have new (iOS 14) and old (iOS 10?-13) configuration UI.

Here's what I noticed, and if anyone has found docs on this, pls add them via an edit or comment:

1- Adding new widgets to Home (Springboard *and* Today view) - I long pressed empty space in my Home page, and it brings up a little rounded-rect plus in the upper left. The UI is what saw in the demos.

2- Adding old widgets to "Today"
If you long press in Today view, you get the plus button at the bottom, and it shows only old widgets in the old config interface.

What does not work, at-this-time:

Home Quick Actions on an app no longer auto-displays the older widgets. (Probably an improvement because this was awkward reuse of UI in a lot of apps), but also important because this display was also a way to "add widget" to Today view.

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone 6s. Does it fail to add, does it fail to list widgets, or fail to show the plus button? (Remember Apple's turned this off for first party apps, you need a legacy iOS13 widget-extended app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the new addition of Widgets, which are a replacement to today extensions, for iOS 14 today extensions will no longer work and need to be converted to a WidgetKit widget.

Comment: Is there any documentation where this is mentioned ?

Comment: If you can reference WWDC or a doc, that would be great. Apple's had several "widgets" and they have been very long-lived. (Dashboard was removed only in Oct 2019.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650350
Based on what the Apple Engineer is saying, for users below iOS 14 as long as you include your Today Extension in your bundle it will still be available, but for iOS 14 users your WidgetKit widget will be the one that is usable.